# How to keep the window generated by the cocoa app on top, the app is launched from terminal

Tags: cocoa, shell

When I launch a cocoa app from terminal, the window generated by the cocoa app stays behind the terminal. Is there a way to keep the window on top?

I tried in the cocoa app :

```
-(void) awakeFromNib {

[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
[self.window setLevel: NSMainMenuWindowLevel]; 

}
```

also tried with setLevel: NSFloatingWindowLevel. Neither works.

or  Should I put the [self.window setLevel: NSFloatingWindowLevel] somewhere else?

Anyone can give some suggestions? Thanks.

LJ

Comment: Is **awaker** FromNib actually in your code, or is that a transcription error?

Comment: sorry, it is a type. I already corrected it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your window the key window and then it would come on top of other windows.

`[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`
`[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]`

And the correct method is `awakeFromNib` not `awakerFromNib`. Ignore if you have declared awaker method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. First, awakeFromNib it is, It is a typo. I tried also with [windowRef makeKeyAndOrderFront:self], no success either. Any clue? Actually, I tried makeKeyAndOrderFront and setLevel (with different settings here), none works for me. :(

Comment: @user1558064 did you replace `windowRef` with your window object ? say `self.window` ?

Comment: it is a nswindowcontroller, so I use self.window, am I right? sorry for the naive question from a beginner.  What is windowRef?

Comment: @user can you add [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; and then check ?

Comment: Yes,  [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] works for me. But Could anyone explain it a little bit why this one works but not the other? Thanks.

Comment: [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] works because it ignores other applications, pops up app window on the top, but [[self window] setLevel: NSFloatingWindowLevel] only for windows in the same app? Am I right? Thanks

Comment: @user Yes the other ones only works for windows within your application.